# npm install didn't work

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

```
$ npm install opn --save
C:\Users\broven\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- opn@4.0.2
  +-- object-assign@4.1.0
  `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
    `-- pinkie@2.0.4
```

I run npm install  in my project dir, but npm won't install package in my project ,even not generate node_modules folder,

Comment: Is there a package.json in the directory where you ran `npm install` from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821698/npm-install-error-issue

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\broven\AppData\Roaming\npm`

I dont think this would be your project directory, you wouldn't run a package json there would you?

Comment: my project directory is another one :'/d/node/angular2-quickstart' ,I run npm in there, but log is this,why this happen..

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npm init` in the root directory of your project before using `npm install`? `npm init` will create a `package.json` file for you.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure why things are not working then. Could you post a picture of your project directory? Also, I would recommend looking through [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) troubleshooting guide.

Answer (score 0):

Based on log seems **C:\Users\broven\AppData\Roaming\npm** is not your project directory. Can you ensure your path and then try installing again.

Comment: I'm sure I run in my project folder